# Problem when removing deprecated bouncy castle provider on android 9

Tags: java, android, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

The following code was working fine on Android 7

```
    KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","BC");
    kg.initialize(spec);
    KeyPair kp = kg.generateKeyPair();
    mKeyEx = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
    mKeyEx.init(kp.getPrivate());
    mPubKeyX509 = kp.getPublic().getEncoded();
    mPubKey = new byte[(spec.getCurve().getField().getFieldSize() + 7) / 8 * 2 + 1];
    System.arraycopy(mPubKeyX509, mPubKeyX509.length - mPubKey.length, mPubKey, 0, mPubKey.length);
```

As you know bouncy castle has been deprecated on Android 9,so i changed first line to:

```
 KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
```

I get the following message error  :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0f00007b:elliptic curve routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNKNOWN_GROUP
```

On the following line

```
mPubKeyX509 = kp.getPublic().getEncoded();
```

Any help please ?

Comment: This depends on what `spec` is, so you need to include it in your code. Java providers have the annoying problem with not being **fail fast**, i.e. often keys are "constructed" and then only if you perform an operation then you'll find out they're not valid.

Comment: i can share spec with you if you don't mind, the problem is that my spec are working fine in android 7. Thank you for your help